# SVM parameter tuning for unbalanced classes (with class weights)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, cross-validation, unbalanced-classes

I am trying to run an SVM on an imbalanced dataset (0-90%, 1-10%) using the e1071 package, with the radial kernel. I am using cross-validation to select the best gamma and cost. Additionally, I want to use class weights ("0"=1, "1"=10) for every model.

This is the code I am using (similar to the one used in ISLR, only with class weights) with 5 gamma values and 5 cost parameters. Instead of getting 25 models in the output, I am getting 5. The cost parameter is not getting accounted for:

[image]

The best model output is the following:
[image]

What is the best way to tune the parameters (gamma and cost), including the class weights?

This is my first time running svm. This code took more than 2 days to run. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: see http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting for how to add the code in text as opposed to images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call is ignoring the `cost` parameter because it isn't part of the list you passed to ranges.  Your call should look like this:

```
tune.out <- tune(svm, RESPONSE~., data = train, kernel="radial", 
                 ranges = list(gamma=c(0.1,0.5,1,2,4), 
                               cost = c(0.1,1,10,100,1000)
                               ), 
                 class.weights= c("0" = 1, "1" = 10))
```

A similar examples is shown in the documentation (`?tune`) with the `iris` dataset.

```
obj <- tune(svm, Species~., data = iris, 
              ranges = list(gamma = 2^(-1:1), cost = 2^(2:4)),
              tunecontrol = tune.control(sampling = "fix")
             )
```

As for why it is taking so long I don't know how large your dataset is (it may just take a while to process it all) but a `cost` of 1000 is really high.  Increasing the cost parameter makes the model more computationally expensive and also increases the risk of losing the ability to generalize your model.  I would start with a lower sequence of cost parameters and keep checking to see if you performance continues to go up with increasing the cost parameter **making sure to evaluate your model on an independent test set!!!**